# VS2013 freezes as I type OpenCV include header files

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, opencv-features2d

I have a problem with VS2013. I'm trying to write a program in vc++ using opencv and in vs2013 update 4 IDE. the problem is as I ***just type*** these lines, my computer freezes. infact the hard activity runs to 100 percent and never stops untill restart. even when I (hardly) close VS and even when I logged off, hard disk activity is still at maximum. the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
```

It seems that the last line makes the problem.
FYI I have tried and run lots of OpenCV examples in VS2013. 
And when I tried the code above on VS2012 on another computer it works well, but on VS2013 on another computer it again freezes just like my computer.
So what's wrong here?

Comment: do you use resharper ?

Comment: No. I don't use resharper. any idea with my problem?

Comment: yes, I have some ideas and I'll add an answer reflecting all possible to overcome the issue

Comment: maybe intellisense indexing or something takes a lot of your system ressources?

Comment: I don't know.. how can I enable or disable intellisense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may point to several performance issues in VS2013, please try each one of the following separately until overcoming the issue:

1. Disabling Synchronized Settings: Go to **Tools -> Options -> Environment-> Synchronized Settings** and remove this option by unchecking the checkbox.
2. Set Current source control plug-in to None: **Tools > Options > Source
   Control**
3. Clear the **"Use hardware graphics acceleration if available"** check
   box to prevent the use of hardware graphics acceleration : **Tools -> Options -> Environment-> General** , make sure **"Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance"** is cleared too.

**Note**: You can select or clear the **"Enable rich client visual experience"** check box to make sure that rich visuals are always on or off, respectively. When this check box is selected, rich visuals are used independent of the computer environment. For example, rich visuals are used when you run Visual Studio locally on a rich client and over remote desktop. it may help too.

4. Try deleting the solution's .suo file (it's next to the .sln file),
   closing and re-opening Visual Studio

[image: Environment-> General]

Comment: It seems that it helps, but partially... . I did all the steps and created a new project . this time as I typed that line, VS and all my computer freezes, then every windows ( VS, Google chrome, even taskbar) start to flash, being Not Responding, disappearing and again being visible. finally after about one minute or two every things turned  normal. now I'm curious about how can I prevent computer from flashing in that manner as I type that line? FYI ram usage was very high during flashing.

Comment: You can read more about it here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Dd744765(v=VS.85).aspx